# Is "Yehud" a proper term for the Hebrews (ancient or otherwise)?

Tags: words

Reading an article about trauma in Jewish history I found the term ***"Yehud"*** (in addition to other terms) indicating the society, culture or community, for instance [1]:

> Jeremiah W. Cataldo  "Memory , Trauma and Identity in Ezra–Nehemiah"
>
> [...] The exile is redefined as a collective
> trauma - Ezra-Nehemiah's cause of conviction - for the *golah* community
> and not the *Am Ha'arets* or even directly  those Judeans remaining in
> Babylon. It provides the basis for legitimation  of *golah* collective
> identity as that of a group predisposed to social-political  authority
> within ***Yehud*** [...].

Is this a proper term for the historic Jewish community (in interfaith discussions or writings)? [This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15779) references the term; but, does not dig into its meaning or connotation.

---

*[update, on request] *Disclaimer: I've not yet an opinion on it, the cite doesn't mean that I share or oppose the view/approach of the author*

Here is the opening of the article:

> Ruth Leys’s theory on trauma and memory, when used as a heuristic
> device,  reveals  qualities  of  Ezra–Nehemiah  that  frame  the  text
> as  an  autotelic  response to a constructed, or fabricated, on the
> part of Ezra–Nehemiah, form  of  ‘survivor’s  guilt’.  While  the
> experiences  of  the  exiles  helped  shape  the  community’s
> collective identity, the events themselves, while important, were  not
> the primary bases for golah identity. It was, as Leys’s theory on
> responses  to trauma as identity narratives helps clarify, the golah
> community’s experience in Yehud that resulted in its internally
> legitimated response of identity.  This response, the intent of which
> served to mobilize collective identity, supported a central belief
> that a restored ‘Israel’ was the end-goal of the experiences of the
> Judean exiles. Read this way, Ezra–Nehemiah exposes itself as [...]"

Also I remembered the link now. It was (a  preprint?) at "academia.edu", see here: https://www.academia.edu/5787739/Memory_Trauma_in_Ezra-Nehemiah

Sources:

1. Article in "Methods , Theories , Imagination - Social Scientific Approaches in  Biblical Studies (2014)"   , [see book table of contents and commercial info](http://www.sheffieldphoenix.com/showbook.asp?bkid=277)

Comment: The question you linked to does reference Yehud and provides a link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yehud_Medinata

Comment: Hmm, do you want to say, that the author talks about that province only? (I was thinking that the article concerns the whole community as the bible writes about it - then I must have a gross misunderstanding here)

Comment: The paragraph is too small for me to understand what he is trying to say, but it sounds like he is trying to distinguish between the Jews who returned to Israel and had a community within Israel/Yehud and those who stayed back in the main babylonian cities within the province of babylon. All while only using the names of locations as named by the governing body during that time.

Comment: This appears to be off-topic, as it's about Jews and not Judaism.

Comment: @msh210 : I'm a bit surprised, especially in view of the link to the other question which I'd found - it could have been a specific term/have a specific meaning in judaism (my original question was *"Is the term 'Yehud' somehow conversational or scientific or generic for the (ancient[?]) hebrew community?")*. But please feel free to "close" the question, I've already pondered to "delete" it at all after having arrived at the feeling, that I had not really understood the focus of the article with the first reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Yehud" is an odd word choice in some ways, but just fine in other ways.  In the context cited, it's used correctly to refer to the Babylonian-controlled province.

The words Yehud, Yehuda, Judah, Judea, and Jew all basically mean the same thing, though often refer to slightly different things depending on the context.

It basically refers to the Southern Kingdom of Israel which consisted of two tribes, Yehuda and Benjamin, as well as some members of the tribe of Levi. Also known as the Kingdom of Yehuda, Yehud, or Judea.

It is not a good choice if referring to all 12 tribes in ancient times, but is just fine if speaking specifically of the Kingdom of Judah or the Babylonian-controlled province.

Comment: I understand now, that it is nearest to "Judea" here; I've still a vague feeling, that the author want to mean more than the geographical region (and its inhabitants) but well ...  the more I read the article the less I'm inclined to put this question deeper. Thanks for the help and "accepted" to close the case  ( ah, and thanks to @Lee for having nicely cleaned up my question)

Comment: In the late biblical period, you'd refer to a Jew as a "yehudi" or the Jews as "the yehudim."

Comment: This is just a common scholarly convention. See my answer, below.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a scholarly convention. In modern English academic literature about ancient Israel and Judah, the pre-exilic Southern kingdom is referred to as "Judah." During the Persian period, when we talk about the place to which the Jewish communities returned (think Ezra and Nehemiah), we call this geographical entity "Yehud." And finally, during the Hellenistic period on (I don't know when this changes in late antique scholarship), we refer to the land as "Judea."

In this particular case, since the author is discussing the Persian period, he follows the common convention and refers to "Yehud" as the place in which the golah and *ʕam hāʔāreṣ* live.

Comment: Thanks @jackweinbender for your information! I'll also look at the article again.